Implementing Register-like behaviour with rxjs
I'm very new to rxjs and declarative programming in general, so apologies if this is a foolish question!
I am, in Typescript, trying to implement behaviour similar to that of a digital register, in that I have two input boolean observables, let's say A and B, and an output register O (also boolean)
Functionality:

O should start with default value "false"
When B goes from FALSE to TRUE, O should update itself with the current value of A
In all other cases, the current value of O should remain static

What I am trying to do is, when B becomes true, save the value of A, so that when B becomes false again I can then use the value of A
I've seen this question, but I'm not able to bridge the gap from its answer to my requirement
I think that I can use pairwise() on B to detect the case when B goes from FALSE to TRUE (previousValue === false && currentValue === true) in conjunction with withLatestFrom to query the current value of A and update the value of O.
What I do not understand is how, in all other cases, I can re-emit/retain the current value of O. As far as I can tell, there is no way to tell, within a pipe operator when defining the Observable O, to reference its current value

The quickest way I could find to fulfil your requirements is to come up with the following:

Input observables a$ and b$ as BehaviorSubject and ReplaySubject respectively.

a$: BehaviorSubject<string>: Emit either default value or the last value emitted to it (using eg. a$.next()) to it's subscribers including future subscribers. If you wish for a different behavior you could change it either with ReplaySubject with buffer 1 (emit the last emitted value but without a default value) or Subject (does not emit previous emission to future subscribers).
b$: ReplaySubject<boolean>(1): Emit the last emitted value to it's future subscribers.


Observable bTransformer$ that takes care of your requirements using the following operators:

distinctUntilChanged - will only emit when the values of b$ changes i.e. true -> false or false -> true.
pairwise - emits previous and current emissions as array either [true, false] or [false, true].
combineLatestWith(a$) - combine with the value of a$ eg. [[true, false], 'value of a'].
filter - emit only when b$ changes from false -> true.
map - emit the value of a$.


Output observable o$ - starts with value false using the operator startWith and emit whenever bTransformer$ emits.

Note that with the current implementation, o$ will also emit whenever a value is emitted to a$ since it's wired it using the combineLatestWith$ operator.
Try the following:


const { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject, combineLatestWith, distinctUntilChanged, pairwise, filter, startWith, map } = rxjs;

const a$ = new BehaviorSubject('value of a');
const b$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
const bTransformer$ = b$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),                // emit only when b$ changes
  pairwise(),                            // emit previous and new values: either [true, false] or [false, true]
  combineLatestWith(a$),                 // combine with the value of a$: eg. [[true, false], 'value of a']
  filter(([[bValueOld]]) => !bValueOld), // destructure the pairwise value of b and emit only if it's [false, true]
  map(([_, a]) => a)                     // emit the value of a
);

const o$ = bTransformer$.pipe(
  startWith(false),                      // always start the subscription to o$ with 'false'
);

function onClickB(value) {
  b$.next(value);
}

function emitValueA() {
  const value = document.getElementById('a-input').value;
  a$.next(value);
}

o$.subscribe(console.log);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="onClickB(true)">Emit true to b</button>
<button onclick="onClickB(false)">Emit false to b</button>
<br>
<br>
<input id="a-input"/>
<button onclick="emitValueA()">Emit value to a</button>




Keeping it simple, with a single stream and a variable that stores the register state.

We first create two checkbox to record A and B actions and C to show output.
A: <input type="checkbox" id="A" /><br />
B: <input type="checkbox" id="B" /><br />
<div id="C">false</div>

We get the elements using javascript.
const a: any = document.getElementById('A') as HTMLElement;
const b: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('B') as HTMLElement;
const c: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('C') as HTMLElement;

Using fromEvent and map, we listen for a checkbox click and take only the checked property of the event using map.
const checkboxStream = (element: any) => {
  return fromEvent(element, 'input').pipe(
    map((event: any) => event?.target?.checked)
  );
};

After that we listen for input event and subscribe to the events from B, since that is the trigger to store the checkbox value.
A simple if condition, will update the state of the register (registerState)  when b is true, else retain the register state.
let registerState = a.checked;
checkboxStream(b)
  .pipe(
    map((bChecked: Array<boolean>) => {
      if (bChecked) {
        registerState = a.checked;
      }
      return registerState;
    })
  )
  .subscribe((cChecked: boolean) => {
    c.innerText = cChecked.toString();
    console.log(cChecked);
  });

Stackblitz Demo
